# PyQt - QGridLayout without changing Qwidget Geometry?

Tags: widget, geometry, pyqt4, grid-layout

I'm working with PyQt and I was wondering if there is any way to set a grid layout in a window so that, for example, one button's geometry wouldn't be affected by the configuration of the layout - because I'm trying to have my button in a square shape and, with the grid layout, it always becomes a long rectangle.

Also, I have multiple rows and columns, and to edit each minimum size would be horrifying. So, is there is any way to establish the geometry of a widget in a grid layout?

UPDATE: my grid

```
    self.Grid = QtGui.QGridLayout()
    self.Grid.addWidget(self.Button1,0,0)
    self.Grid.addWidget(self.Box1,2,1)
    self.Grid.addWidget(self.Box2,2,3)
    self.Grid.addWidget(self.Button2,0,4,Qt.AlignRight)
    self.Grid.setRowMinimumHeight(1,50)
    self.Grid.setRowMinimumHeight(1,50)
    self.Grid.setRowMinimumHeight(3,250)
    self.Grid.setColumnMinimumWidth(0,100)
    self.Grid.setColumnMinimumWidth(2,50)
    self.Grid.setColumnMinimumWidth(4,100)
    self.setLayout(self.Grid)
```

Comment: Difficult to be sure without seeing the actual layout you are using, but setting a maximum size for the button may work.

Comment: @ekhumoro How can I set a maximum size for the buttom. And also, setting it doesn't mean that it would be the shape I want, it's possible that the button can access to that geometry no?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the example code in your question, just add something like the following:

```
    self.Button1.setMinimumSize(50, 50)
    self.Button1.setMaximumSize(50, 50)
```

or:

```
    self.Button1.setFixedSize(50, 50)
```

Comment: YES! "setFixedSize" method worked! Thank you very much, it was what I was searching!!! ^^